# Streamlit-webrtc with custom video source

Tags: webrtc, streamlit

I'm working on a traffic detection project, where I get video stream from Youtube livestream using CamGear and then process each frame with OpenCV. I want to display final video with detections in Streamlit app. I tried passing processed frames to st.frame, but for some reason only first few frames are shown and then the video freezes. Now I am looking at using webrtc component, but I can’t figure out, how to change video source from webcam. Thanks.